# Increment 2 variables in paralell Node-RED

Tags: javascript, mqtt, node-red

I am trying to create a script that creates 2 variables, and increments each one of them based on a condition. The actualNetWeight is received in real-time with a MQTT connection to a server and the values are displayed in a line chart. When this value is over or equals to 0.500, I have to count that item entry as an "ok" item, and if its under 0.500, I should count it as a "under" item. The problem is that initializing these variables as I have in my code, resets them to 0 every time a new value is received, making the counters go only from 0 to 1 when the condition is met, and back to 0 when the condition is not met. So in logical terms this script works, but it only does half it's job. I have tried many different ways of approaching this but can't seem to get the needed results. I have also looked in Node-RED forums but there is pretty much no useful information on this tool online at all.

```
var ok = 0;
var under = 0;
var scartoTotale;
var actualNetWeight = msg.payload.actualNetWeight.value;
var numeroPezziTot = msg.payload.identity;

if(actualNetWeight >= 0.500)
{
    ok++;
}
else
{
    under++;
    scartoTotale += (0.500 - actualNetWeight);
}

msg.payload.ok = ok;
msg.payload.under = under;
msg.payload.scartoTotale = scartoTotale;
return msg;
```

The 'msg' is standard for Node-RED and the payload is the response I get from the server, from which I receive my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that the code in the function node all gets run each time a new message arrives at the input.

So the first 2 lines will always set the `ok` and `under` variables to 0.

If you want to store state between messages then you need to use what is known as the context. Details here https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#storing-data

To fix your code you need to change things as follows:

```
var ok = context.get('ok')||0;;
var under = context.get('under')||0;;
var scartoTotale;
var actualNetWeight = msg.payload.actualNetWeight.value;
var numeroPezziTot = msg.payload.identity;

if(actualNetWeight >= 0.500)
{
    ok++;
}
else
{
    under++;
    scartoTotale += (0.500 - actualNetWeight);
}

context.set('ok', ok)
context.set('under', under)

msg.payload.ok = ok;
msg.payload.under = under;
msg.payload.scartoTotale = scartoTotale;
return msg;
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I did to fix it. I found out about the context usage in the Node red forum in an unrelated topic and took it from there. Took me ages though. I just came here to close this question cause I didnt think anyone would have answered, but found your answer. Thank you so much either way! Gave your answer an upvote and marked it as a solution. Thanks again for the answer and for your time